# asp.net core 2.0 app.Run call twice?

Tags: asp.net-core

when i create new project empty in asp.net core 2.0, and write some code. And debug, but i see app.Run run twice once when i refresh in browser, but i don't understand why? somebody help me
see this code in program.cs
[code in program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrq9k.png)

and see this code in startup.cs
[code in startup.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHhwU.png)

i don't understand i is always even(0,2,4,6,8....n), but i debug code, i can old (1,3,5,7.....), and app.Run call to twice. why? help me understand it.

Comment: please edit the question and paste the code inside. Don't attach code as screenshot.

Answer (score 9):

If you check the request URL for the second request, I am sure you will find it is for *http://yoururl/favicon.ico*.

Browsers request for the "favicon" always so they can show it on the tab. This is a feature of browsers, nothing is wrong in your app.

Comment: oh, Thank you so much. I use F12 in browser and i see this. Thank you, again.

Comment: I add a bit more details in a https://stackoverflow.com/a/56888548/5407323

Thanks, juunas.